# Get resultSet keys in phonegap?

Tags: ios, sql, cordova

With say 5 fields in the DB, I know the columns that can be queried and use:

```
function getDetails_success (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;

    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

        var content = results.rows.item(i);
        buf += '<tr '+ content.key1+'>';
        buf += '<tr '+ content.key2+'>';
    }
}
```

and so on.

What if I have 50 fields, of which 5 random fields has to be displayed. Do I get the keys from the resultset? What are the various ways I can approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 5 random fields are selected by the user to be displayed, put all of them in an array.

```
var randomFieldsSelected = new Array();
randomFieldsSelected.push(selection1);
randomFieldsSelected.push(selection2); //and so on
```

Instead of the above for loop, put,

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {

    var content = results.rows.item(i);
    buf += '<tr '+ content[randomFieldsSelected[i]]+'>';
}
```

(The above works,provided, the database column names match with 'selection1' and 'selection2' etc)